# Not able to choose apple watch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

Normally, I can run apple watch app from choosing apple watch in the scheme. However, for some project,  I see like this. I can't choose simulator for that. May I know how to do?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried autocreating the schemes again? Go Manage Schemes -> 'Autocreate Schemes Now' and see if this fixes it.

Comment: Cool. I've formalised the answer so this can help people who visit this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, when this happens, a simple reset is all that's required.

Go to **Manage Schemes -> 'Autocreate Schemes Now'**, this should re-generate the schemes for you with the right target devices (including simulator).